# Multivariate regression from scratch error

Tags: r

I'm computing multivariate regression from scratch. 
I have this code:

```
#Multivariate regression 
  set.seed(18814)
  n = 200
  p = 300
  real_p=4
  X=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
  y <- apply(X[,1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n)
  data1=cbind(X,y)
  betas <- solve(t(X) %*% X)%*%t(X) %*% y

  #Using lm()
  data1=as.data.frame(data1)
  lm=lm(y~X, data = data1)
  lm$coefficients
```

In the first part of the code I compute it by scratch, and then I do it using the `lm()` function.

I get this error for the scratch version:

**Error in solve.default(t(X) %*% X) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.73902e-20**

I don't understand what it means!

Using the `lm()` function I get the coefficients but a lot of them are `NA`'s. 
What could I do so that I would have the same solution as using `lm` even with the `NA`'s.

I would very much appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You have more variables than observations. That's a no go if you want to use your solution to estimate parameters.

Comment: "computationally singular" means that the coefficients can't be uniquely determined from the data (because there are more variables than observations in the regression model). Specifically, the matrix X'X (where X is the design matrix for the regression and X' is its transpose) doesn't have a unique inverse. But this matrix needs to be invertible to determine all of the regression coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  have to keep the number of data observations more than the number of data attributes in the data

do changes like in the below :

```
 set.seed(18814)
 n = 300
 p = 200
 real_p=4
 X=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
 y <- apply(X[,1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n)
 data1=cbind(X,y)
 betas <- solve(t(X) %*% X)%*%t(X) %*% y

 #Using lm()
 data1=as.data.frame(data1)
 lm=lm(y~X, data = data1)
 lm$coefficients
```

in the above case it won't give error and also the coefficients aren't NA values

Comment: if the number of data observations are more than the number of data attributes then there aren't sufficient differential equations to be formed to determine the coefficients in regression

Comment: I don't think you're using the term differential equations correctly here

Comment: may be, but inside mathematics and derivation do include partial differentiation. Suggest something to represent this idea correctly.